# display an entire arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing, display

I'm still pretty new to java.  Am trying to make a program that basically adds contacts to an array list.  I have figured everything out as far as creating a new object and setting the name/number.  As far as I can tell it's adding it to the array, however I'm not sure how I can display the array?  I want to add a snippet of code that would display the array list after you add each contact.

Here is my contact class, not sure if I need the PhoneBook method or not for the array....

```js
public class Contact {
  String first; //first name
  String last; //last name
  String phone; //phone number
  String PhoneBook; //array list???

  public void PhoneBook(String f, String l, String p) {
    first = f;
    last = l;
    phone = p;

  }

  public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
  }

  public void setLast(String last) {
    this.last = last;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public Contact makeCopy() {
      Contact Contact = new Contact();
      Contact.first = this.first;
      Contact.last = this.last;
      Contact.phone = this.phone;
      return Contact;
    } //end makeCopy
} //end class Computer
```

Here is my driver class...

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class contactDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Contact Contact = new Contact(); //make default Contact
      Contact newContact;

      String first; //first name
      String last; //last name
      String phone; //phone number
      String input; //answer to create a new contact

      boolean add = true; //boolean to add new contact

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      Contact.setFirst("Default");
      Contact.setLast("Default");
      Contact.setPhone("Default");

      while (add) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to create a new contact? (Y/N)");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y")) {
          newContact = Contact.makeCopy();

          System.out.println("Enter the contact's first name: ");
          first = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter the contact's last name: ");
          last = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter the contact's phone number: ");
          phone = scan.nextLine();

          ArrayList < Contact > PhoneBook = new ArrayList();
          newContact.setFirst(first);
          newContact.setLast(last);
          newContact.setPhone(phone);
          PhoneBook.add(newContact);
        } else {
          add = false;
          System.out.println("Goodbye!");
          break;
        }
      }
    } //end main
} //end Class ComputerDriver
```

Comment: Also, not sure why the code will compile but it keeps saying Warnings from last compilation contactDriver.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.... any idea what this means?  Thanks!!

Comment: You are making a new ArrayList each time through the while(add)  loop. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: thank you for clarifying... i know my code was probably a little messy and not perfect, but I'm still learning so thanks for not going too hard on me.  I moved the array creation outside of the loop and the error went away. I also changed the if statement so now you type N to add new contact, D to display phone book, and Q to quit.  Works much better than displaying it each time.  Now I just need to figure out how to validate the phone number to ensure there are 10 digits.  Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just for printing, override the `toString` method of your `Contact` class, which will be like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return first + " " + last + "; phone number: " + phone;
}
```

Then, in your `main` method, print all the contacts by doing:

```
for (Contact c : phoneBook) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Also, you should create the phoneBook, which is an `ArrayList` outside of your loop.

Your `Contact` class should be defined as:

```
public class Contact {
    private String first; // first name
    private String last; // last name
    private String phone; // phone number

    public Contact(String f, String l, String p) {
        first = f;
        last = l;
        phone = p;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public Contact makeCopy() {
        return new Contact(first, last, phone);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return first + " " + last + "; phone number: " + phone;
    }
}
```

And your `main` method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Contact> phoneBook = new ArrayList<>();

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to create a new contact? (Y/N)");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the contact's first name: ");
            String first = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the contact's last name: ");
            String last = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the contact's phone number: ");
            String phone = scan.nextLine();

            Contact contact = new Contact(first, last, phone);
            phoneBook.add(contact);
            for (Contact c : phoneBook) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            break;
        }
    }

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help... i followed your lead but changed my if statement to make it more user friendly and also added phone number validation... i'll post the new code at the end if you care to see!  THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: @JordanHawkes you're very welcome! It's great if you can post your final code

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will give warning, most likely because of this:

```
String PhoneBook;
```

when you know that you also have

```
public void PhoneBook(String f, String l, String p)
```

and even more another PhoneBook

```
ArrayList < Contact > PhoneBook = new ArrayList();
```

try to use another variable name and function name to be safe and make sure they are different especially for

```
String PhoneBook;
public void PhoneBook(String f, String l, String p)
```

since they are under same class.

In terms of data structure, you have a wrong concept here. first is, this:

```
ArrayList < Contact > PhoneBook = new ArrayList();
```

should be outside the while loop so for whole your application, you will not replace your phone book after looping. to print them, later just use

```
for(int i = 0; i < phoneBook.size(); i++)
    your printing
```

Comment: print somewhere, should be outside and after your while loop, or also can be inside your else

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create some Getters. Most IDE's will do this for you.

For example, in your contact class add this:

```
public String getFirst(){ return first; }
```

Then do that for all of the items you want. When you want to print them out, set up a for each loop in your driver class like this:

```
for(Contact contact : PhoneBook){
    System.out.println("Contact details: " + contact.getFirst() + " " + contact.getLast() + ", Phone #: " + contact.getPhoneNumber());
}
```

Alternatively, you could also create a method in you contacts class that takes the println contents from above and spits it out. For example:

```
public void printContactDetails(){ System.out.println("...");}
```

then in your for each loop call: `contact.printContactDetails();`

Answer (score 0):

You just override `toString()` method of your `Contact` class, and in `main()` method, directly call your `ArrayList`'s `toString()`.

Here is my example:

```
package somepackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Inner> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Inner in = new Inner("name" + i, "address" + i);
            list.add(in);
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }


    private static class Inner {

        private String name;
        private String address;

        Inner(String name, String address) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "name:" + name + ", " + "address: " + address + "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Screen outputs:

```
[name:name0, address: address0
, name:name1, address: address1
, name:name2, address: address2
, name:name3, address: address3
, name:name4, address: address4
, name:name5, address: address5
, name:name6, address: address6
, name:name7, address: address7
, name:name8, address: address8
, name:name9, address: address9
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out thanks to your guys help!  I changed the if statement so you can now add a new contact, display the phone book, or quit.  I also added phone number validation!  Here is the updated code if anyone cares!

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class contactDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String first; //first name
      String last; //last name
      String phone = ""; //phone number
      String input; //answer to create a new contact

      boolean add = true; //boolean to add new contact
      boolean phoneValid; //boolean to validate phone number

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      ArrayList < Contact > PhoneBook = new ArrayList < > ();

      while (add) {
        phoneValid = false;

        System.out.println("Type (N) to add a new contact, (D) to display your phonebook, or (Q) to quit!");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
          System.out.println("Enter the contact's first name: ");
          first = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Enter the contact's last name: ");
          last = scan.nextLine();

          while (!phoneValid) {
            System.out.println("Enter the contact's phone number: XXX-XXX-XXXX");
            phone = scan.nextLine();
            if (phone.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) {
              phoneValid = true;
              break;
            } else {
              System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that!");
            }
          }

          Contact contact = new Contact(first, last, phone);
          PhoneBook.add(contact);
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
          add = false;
          System.out.println("Goodbye!");
          break;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
          for (Contact c: PhoneBook) {
            System.out.println(c);
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that!");
        }
      }
    } //end main
} //end Class ComputerDriver
```